# one side border of a paragraph

Tags: html, css

I am trying show a left border for a paragraph using :before class.

But the output seems bit different from what I want to achieve.

Code:

```css
p.left-border::before {
    border-left: 3px solid #9e9464;
    content:"";
    padding: 0 20px 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
p {
    line-height:30px;
}
```

```html
 <h4>Our Unique Approach</h4>

<p class="left-border">Aspire to Acheive is unlike anything you’ve ever experienced. The Fellowship brings together some of the world’s most creative and motivated young people, and helps them bring their most ambitious projects to life. Thiel Fellows are given a grant of $100,000 to focus on their work, their research, and their self-education while outside of university.</p>
```

Here is the link to a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/e12pk3bp/) of what I have done so far.

Here is the screenshot of what I want to achieve:

[image: Screen shot of a paragraph of text with a green border to the left that goes down 3 lines but not the entire length of the paragraph.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe so?

```css
p {
    line-height:30px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
p.left-border::before {    
    content:"";
    position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 0;    
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 60%;
    width: 5px;
    background: #9e9464;
}
```

```html
<h4>Our Unique Approach</h4>

<p class="left-border">Aspire to Acheive is unlike anything you’ve ever experienced. The Fellowship brings together some of the world’s most creative and motivated young people, and helps them bring their most ambitious projects to life. Thiel Fellows are given a grant of $100,000 to focus on their work, their research, and their self-education while outside of university.</p>
```

Comment: Brilliant just awesome. That's what I was looking for. I will go through the code to understand. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible by positioning the before element `absolute`, like so:
http://jsfiddle.net/e12pk3bp/2/

Comment: Thanls Jm for your help.